# R 3.6 configuration in SPSS subscription

Tags: r, spss

I am trying to configure R 3.6.3 using the STATS_R36_CONFIGURATION. When I try to configure, SPSS asks for the R 3.6 home directory. I cannot find it. Any idea where it would be. I am using a MAC running Mojave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type this in an R console:

```
R.home()
```

On my Mac running Mojave I get:

```
R.home()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
```

You should probably also go over the R Mac FAQ. When running R in R.app the FAQ is one of the choices in the Help dropdown menu.

Comment: Hello @SeanChickery. Welcome to SO. If this answer resolved your problem, please accept and upvote it.